# Angular POST or PUT request

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

i proceed to tell my problem:

I create an Angular proyect, so i created:

---

**1. Model with Interface "Articulo":**

```
export interface Articulo {
    IdArticulo: number;
    Nombre: string;
    Precio: number;
    CodigoDeBarra: string;
    IdArticuloFamilia: number;
    Stock: number;
    FechaAlta: number;
    Activo: boolean;
}
```

---

**2. "Articulo" Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Articulo } from "src/app/models/articulo";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";


@Injectable({providedIn: "root"}
)


export class ArticulosService {
  
  resourceUrl: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.resourceUrl = "https://pav2.azurewebsites.net/api/articulos/";
  }
```

```
post(obj:Articulo):{
  return this.httpClient.post<Articulo>(this.resourceUrl, obj);
  }

put(Id: number, obj:Articulo) {
  return this.httpClient.put<Articulo>(this.resourceUrl + Id, obj);
  }
```

---

**3."Articulo" Component :**

- These are the Reactive Forms:

```
 // Creación de Objetos Formularios Reactivos

  FormBusqueda = new FormGroup({
    Nombre: new FormControl(null),

    Activo: new FormControl(null),
    });

  FormRegistro = new FormGroup({
    IdArticulo: new FormControl(0),

    Nombre: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      Validators.maxLength(55)
      ]),

    Precio: new FormControl(null, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]{1,7}')
      ]),

    Stock: new FormControl(null, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]{1,7}')
      ]),

    CodigoDeBarra: new FormControl ('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]{1,7}')
      ]),

    IdArticuloFamilia: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
      ]),

    FechaAlta: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/](0[1-9]|1[012])[-/](19|20)[0-9]{2}')
      ]),

    Activo: new FormControl(true),
    });
```

- This is the **.ts** block of code that have a Record function: **(itemCopy have the error, ignore '---''---')**

```
 // grabar tanto altas como modificaciones
  Grabar() {

    this.submitted = true;

    // Verificamos que no permita grabar si no cumple con los Validators del Form
    if(this.FormRegistro.invalid){

      return;
    }
    
    //hacemos una copia de los datos del formulario, para modificar la fecha y luego enviarlo al servidor
    const itemCopy = { ...this.FormRegistro.value };
    
    //convertir fecha de string dd/MM/yyyy a ISO para que la entienda webapi
    if (typeof itemCopy.FechaAlta === 'string'){ 

      var arrFecha = (itemCopy.FechaAlta).substring(0, 10).split("/");
      if (arrFecha.length == 3 && typeof arrFecha === 'string')
        itemCopy.FechaAlta = new Date(arrFecha[2], arrFecha[1] - 1, arrFecha[0]).toISOString();
    }

    // agregar: post
    if (this.AccionABMC == "A") {
      this.articulosService.post(---itemCopy---).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.Volver();
      alert('Registro agregado correctamente.');
      this.Buscar();
    });
    } 
    
    else {
    // modificar: put
    this.articulosService.put(itemCopy.IdArticulo, ---itemCopy---).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.Volver();
      alert('Registro modificado correctamente.');
      this.Buscar();
    });
    }
  }
```

---

**And the error is the next --> .ts(2345):**

- ***In "this.articulosService.post":***

---

```
const itemCopy: {
    IdArticulo?: number;
    Nombre?: string;
    Precio?: any;
    Stock?: any;
    CodigoDeBarra?: string;
    IdArticuloFamilia?: string;
    FechaAlta?: string;
    Activo?: boolean;
}
Argument of type '{ IdArticulo?: number; Nombre?: string; Precio?: any; Stock?: any; CodigoDeBarra?: string; IdArticuloFamilia?: string; FechaAlta?: string; Activo?: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Articulo'.
  Property 'IdArticulo' is optional in type '{ IdArticulo?: number; Nombre?: string; Precio?: any; Stock?: any; CodigoDeBarra?: string; IdArticuloFamilia?: string; FechaAlta?: string; Activo?: boolean; }' but required in type 'Articulo'.ts(2345)
```

---

- ***In "this.articulosService.put":***

```
const itemCopy: {
    IdArticulo?: number;
    Nombre?: string;
    Precio?: any;
    Stock?: any;
    CodigoDeBarra?: string;
    IdArticuloFamilia?: string;
    FechaAlta?: string;
    Activo?: boolean;
}
Argument of type '{ IdArticulo?: number; Nombre?: string; Precio?: any; Stock?: any; CodigoDeBarra?: string; IdArticuloFamilia?: string; FechaAlta?: string; Activo?: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Articulo'.ts(2345)
```

**This proyect is a copy of:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/78737-pasopasoang-uscmck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodels%2Farticulo.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Farticulos.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Farticulos%2Farticulos.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Farticulos%2Farticulos.component.ts

**But stackblitz proyect is made in Angular 13 and my proyect in Angular 14, so i corrected and redefined a lot of problems. This is out of my hands, i need help.**

Comment: What happens if you removed the types after `.post` and `.put` in your `ArticulosService`? i.e., `this.httpClient.post<any>(this.resourceUrl, obj);` instead of `this.httpClient.post<Articulo>(this.resourceUrl, obj);`
Try making some logs there, compare the sent object with the expected model, check if you are importing the same model.. And yes.. Try removing all the optional operators as well.

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly I did what you say, even i remove .post<> or  .put <>.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that your model `Articulo` also requires `IdArticulo: number` on the object you are trying to `post/put`.

1. Inspect why `IdArticulo` is not given.
2. Try not to "copy" objects and get rid of optionals `?` if they are not actually optional. Seems to me that they are always present https://pav2.azurewebsites.net/api/articulos/
3. Try to use camelCase when naming variables/properties as a good practice.

`ArticulosFamiliasService` should use url?

```
this.resourceUrl = 'https://pav2.azurewebsites.net/api/articulosfamilias';
```

Anyway, seems that `this.ItemsArtFam` is not populated before you go to do your things. Add an `?` before trying `find on it`

```js
 var Nombre = this.ItemsArtFam?.find(x => x.IdArticuloFamilia === Id)?.Nombre;
```

Also added trimming of whitespaces. It was conflicting with your regex checks.

```
itemCopy.CodigoDeBarra = itemCopy.CodigoDeBarra.trim();
```

Seemed to work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/78737-pasopasoang-5xuoks

https://78737-pasopasoang-5xuoks.stackblitz.io/articulos

Strong typing is there to help you (it probably doesn't affect the actual working of the program - yet).